# Retry POST request on 202 response - Faraday gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, faraday

I need `Faraday` to retry my **POST** request every time when it gets 202 http status as a response. I am aware of [this module](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/lostisland/faraday/Faraday/Request/Retry), yet I don't really get how to make use of it, since 202 doesn't throw an error or something and **retry_if:** block is not called for 202 response.

I had some success with [this middleware](https://github.com/grokify/faraday_middleware-request-retry) but it resends request only once, while 202 response may occur 2 and more times in a row.

I wonder if someone could show me a way to do it using `retry` module or Faraday middleware.

Answer (score 0):

in theory 202 is a success https://httpstatuses.com/202, it's an acceptance of an asynchronous request, so you really should only have to send your post once, and if you get a 202, you're done your job. That link states "There is no facility in HTTP for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation." So, I think you'd really need to be checking for completion another way. However, you could do something like this (just spitballing here):

```
   conn = Faraday.new(url: url, :ssl => {:verify => verify_ssl_cert}) do |faraday|
        faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
   end
   response = conn.get
   while response.status == 202
      # repeat code above
   end
```

But you run various risks like infinitely looping